# Dom Exception 12 in Zepto.js

Tags: javascript, exception, dom, zepto, domexception

I'm wondering how to fix this problem in Zepto library. It happend's when I tried to run:

```
$("#pro@");
```

It's pointing line 77 which is:

```
$.qsa = $$ = function(element, selector){
    return slice.call(element.querySelectorAll(selector))
}
```

Can u Help me?

Comment: Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
$.qsa.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What element are you trying to select?  Does it have an @ character in the name? For example:

```
<div id="pro@">
```

The @ character is a reserved character that isn't expected in selectors.  Basically, Zepto or jQuery would be looking for "#pro" plus the "@" selector which it does not understand.

The way to get around this is to escape the @ character.  In CSS you would do "#pro\@" so in JavaScript you need to do:

```
$("#pro\\@");
```

A better strategy would be to just use a-z, 0-9, - and _ in your ID's.